# Typeorm when trying to run migrations: Missing required argument: dataSource

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to run TypeORM migrations with `ormconfig.json` like this

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "ip-is-here",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "name",
  "password": "12345",
  "database": "db1",
  "synchronize": false,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["dist/storage/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/storage/migrations/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/storage",
    "migrationsDir": "src/storage/migrations"
  }
}
```

via `yarn typeorm migration:run` 
But get an error:

```
Missing required argument: dataSource
```

What I have to do?
Thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

TypeOrm removed `ormconfig.json` support in version [0.3.0](https://typeorm.io/changelog#030httpsgithubcomtypeormtypeormpull8616-2022-03-17). You should use new syntax - create `ormconfig.ts` and specify options for you database, for example:

```js
export const connectionSource = new DataSource({
    migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'somehealthchecker',
    logging: false,
    synchronize: false,
    name: 'default',
    entities: ['src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    migrations: ['src/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
});
```

Then, after running the connection:

```js
await connectionSource.initialize();
```

You can get entities by:

```js
const myRepo = connectionSource.getRepository(SomeEntity)
```

Also your scripts in `package.json` should look like this:

```json
"migration:generate": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -d src/modules/config/ormconfig.ts",
"migration:up": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run -d src/modules/config/ormconfig.ts",
"migration:down": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert -d src/modules/config/ormconfig.ts",
```

After the command, just give the name for migration in the console without -n option

Comment: This https://wanago.io/2022/07/25/api-nestjs-database-migrations-typeorm/ is a far more useful tutorial than the official docs

Comment: I am using NestJS, and I had to create an extra file that exports the DataSource object just for this purpose.

Comment: For my Nestjs projects, I also create a separate database configuration file to generate the migrations. I haven't found a way to make TypeOrm read configurations from a module yet, but it looks like TypeOrm can't do that. Since we use our own module system in Nestjs, if we were using Express, for example, we would need to create such a file one way or another, and there would be no problem. But at least it works

Comment: I wish this was written in the documentation

Comment: Then how can we import typeormmodule options in the AppModule? Or we have to write again all the configuration there?

Comment: @RiteshKhatri - Essentially, in the database.module.ts file (which is exactly the imported module), you configure the database connection and other subtle settings that your application will work with. ormconfig.ts can contain a list of basic settings for the same database (or repeat them if you want) and serves only to specify the path to the configuration file in a script to create a structural migration.

Answer (score 9):

with latest typescript if you are using cli setup as per typeorm [setup](https://typeorm.io/using-cli#installing-cli)

then following package.json script will work

```
"scripts": {
   "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/datasources/PostgresDatasource.ts",
}
```

Run `npm run typeorm migration:generate src/migration/initaltables` `npm run typeorm migration:run`

Answer (score 6):

Please don't forget `--`

> If you need to pass parameter with dash to npm script, you will need to add them after --. For example, if you need to generate, the command is like this:
>
> ```
> npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n migrationNameHere
> ```

Docs [here](https://typeorm.io/using-cli#if-entities-files-are-in-typescript).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while following their doc

```
npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -- -d ./src/data-source.ts
```

But it worked removing `--`

```
npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d ./src/data-source.ts
```

So, I updated my package.json a little bit

```
"scripts": {
  "migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d ./src/data-source.ts",
  "migration:revert": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:revert -d ./src/data-source.ts"
}
```

Comment: How to add scripts for generate command for migration in package.json. By the below way --- "generate": "typeorm migration:generate -n PostRefactoring". It is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just figure out that you have to define the path to the file where your Datasource is defined.
In my case:
`yarn typeorm migration:run -d dist/datasources/datasource.js`

Comment: hi,in my case this is have the path:dist/data-source.js but it still not work,can you have another way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the App - Datasource method to initialize your connection and it's quit easier from there

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "ROOT",
    database: "userLog",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true, 
    entities: [User, Student],
    migrations: ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
    migrationsTableName: "custom_migration_table",
    subscribers: ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
})
```

Initialize your connection.

```
AppDataSource.initialize()
  .then(async () => {
    // do anything here like connecting to your express server or adding document to your db
  }
```

If it's a Javascript project, use this CLI command - `typeorm migration:run`

But if your project uses typescript, you can use ts-node in conjunction with typeorm to run .ts migration files. use the following commands

```
"create": "typeorm migration:create ./src/migration/learningMigration"
"generate": "typeorm migration:generate -n PostRefactoring"
"migrate": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d src/data-source", 
"revert": "npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:revert -d src/data-source",
```